# How to continue play video as VideoView layer using AVLayer when app enters in background in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios-background-mode

I am playing video in videoView using AVPLayer but when app enters in background mode and again open the app then video is pause.

```
func playVideo() {

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audios/copy1", ofType:"mp4") {

        let filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)

        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: filePathUrl)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)

        playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.videoPlayer?.currentItem, queue: nil) { (_) in
            self.videoPlayer?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.videoPlayer?.play()
            self.videoPlayer.rate = 0.5
            self.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        }

        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        videoPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you must set up things correctly.

1. You must configure your `AVAudioSession` correctly
2. Disconnect the AVPlayer from your presentation when going in background

For the first point you must set Audio background mode to on and configure the audio session:

```
    do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            let _ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("an error occurred when audio session category.\n \(error)")
        }
```

For the second:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    // Disconnect the AVPlayer from the presentation when entering background

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
    playerViewController.player = nil

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
    playerLayer.player = nil
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Reconnect the AVPlayer to the presentation when returning to foreground

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
    playerViewController.player = player

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
    playerLayer.player = player
}
```

For more info check those documents: 
 
[link1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession)
[link2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio)
[link3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/playing_audio_from_a_video_asset_in_the_background)